# Flip the previewed video in AMCap sample?

Tags: directshow, flip, webcam-capture

I am using a DirectShow sample (AMCap) to capture a live video stream. I want to flip the previewed video horizontally. Does anybody know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on video source, but You can try from: Options-> "Video Capture Filter ...". Source property page will appear and usually can be found horizontal or vertical flipping check.